# Xcode upgrade to 4.2 doesn't actually seem to upgrade anything

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I currently have Xcode 4.1 installed. I attempted to update using the App Store so that I can test my app in iOS 5. The update program downloaded properly, and it took quite a while to perform the update, whereupon Xcode relaunched.

I couldn't find iOS 5 in the deployment target list, and I checked the "About" section, and found that I was still using Xcode 4.1, build 4B110, not Xcode 4.2, build 4D199, as described on the [download Xcode 4.2 page](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

I ran the update again, without any luck. I attempted to download the update again from the app store, but it just has a blue button saying "installed", and no obvious way to force a reinstall. The page on the app store clearly says Xcode 4.2, so that is what I would expect to have by now.

Has anyone run into the same issue? After quite a bit of googling, it would appear that this is not the case. I would be interested to hear any hypotheses, or solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `/Developer` directory to something like `/Developer-4.1`, then install Xcode 4.2 again using `/Developer` as the install path.  After the install, inside `/Developer/Applications/` should be the new Xcode 4.2 that you want to use.

```
[ 16:44 Jonathan@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv /Developer /Developer-4.1
```

This is how my `/` looks like from all the different versions:

```
[ 16:44 Jonathan@MacBookPro / ]$ ll
drwxrwxr-x+ 46 root  admin   1.5K Oct 12 11:52 Applications
drwxrwxr-x  15 root  admin   510B Sep 20 13:27 Developer
drwxrwxr-x@ 17 root  admin   578B Sep 20 13:12 Developer-3.2.4
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 root  admin   340B Sep 20 13:54 Developer-3.2.5
drwxrwxr-x@ 16 root  admin   544B Oct  8 14:23 Developer-4.2
drwxrwxr-x@ 18 root  admin   612B Sep 20 13:44 Developer-4.2-beta7
```

Comment: Well, I was hoping to avoid the scorched earth solution so I could understand exactly what went wrong but I'll give this a shot, thanks.

Comment: Yea, I totally agree, but Apple seems to enjoy making things as difficult as possible, so this is the best solution I have found that works.

Comment: Update: I'm still on Xcode 4.1, apparently. I'm going to try redownloading the installer, perhaps they served me up an old version or something.

Comment: I redownloaded the installer, deleted all old versions of Xcode and installed. All is good with the world. Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have two versions of Xcode installed.

You should see this:[image]

Also you might try removing the 4.1 version of Xcode, checking if there is a 4.2 version and if n to installing it.

The Xcode release docs provide information on uninstalling, here is the script they specify:

Uninstalling Xcode Developer Tools
To uninstall Xcode developer tools on the boot volume along with the  directory, from a Terminal window type:

$ sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

To remove the underlying developer content on the boot volume, but leave the  directory and supporting files untouched, from a Terminal window type:

$ sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=systemsupport

Comment: Spotlight isn't able to find more than one instance of Xcode.app. Nice theory though, I didn't think of that one.

Comment: `uninstall-devtools` is in `/Developer/Library` btw, not `/Library`.

Comment: Interesting, I copy/pasted the info from the 4.2 Xcode dmg about document.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered this same problem, but after some time I found out, that although App Store showed that it had installed XCode 4.2, it had just downloaded something called **Xcode Installer** to the Applications folder. Only after running it, the installer overwrote the Xcode 4.1 to 4.2.

Comment: I didn't get stung by this one, but it confuse me for a minute or two the first time I installed xcode from the app store so +1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I believe that there is no need to rename the dev folder or uninstall Xcode. The solution is, after you update Xcode via the app store, look for a file is called "Install Xcode" in your applications folder. Click on it and it completes the update from 4.1 to 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the developer folder. Install the update. There should be a developer folder now. Run xcode. If you have xcode 4.2, in the main menu, it should say xcode 4.2